# Classic ASP / MSSQL - Remove returned results based on certain conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a little sql query, like so

```
SELECT * FROM table
```

This returns a bunch of results, i output the following fields:

```
ID
UserID
Amount
Date
```

What i want to do is get the most recent entry from each UserID ( based on ID ), then if the amount is 0 do not return ANY results from that UserID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select t1.*
from your_table t1
join
(
  select userid, max(date) as mdate
  from your_table
  group by userid
  having sum(case when amount = 0 then 1 else 0 end) = 0
) t2 on t1.userid = t2.userid and t1.date = t2.mdate
```

In the subquery you group by the user and select only those having no amount of zero. In that select you use `max(date) as mdate` to get the latest date for each user.

That subquery can be joined to the original table to get the complete record and not just the userid.

Comment: Could you explain the max(date) bit for me please

Comment: `max(date)` gets the latest date for each user. `mdate` is just an alias name for that column.

Comment: Ahhh that makes sense .. i will try it and see how i go, thanks

Comment: Im getting a 500 when running it .. hmmm .. Can a smalldate field have a max put on it?

Comment: `max()` can be applied on every data type. But I don't get what you mean by 500? Is this an error code?

Comment: Yes ... 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: That seems to be an other issue and not about this specific query itself.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT 
        MAX(ID) OVER (PARTITION BY UserID) MaxIDForUserID,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY ID DESC) rn,        
        UserID, 
        Amount,
        Date
    FROM TableName
)

SELECT * FROM cte WHERE rn = 1 AND Amount != 0
```